# uitableview sections with cells from two arrays

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I've been following two tutorials online and been trying to combine them with the goal of having a tableview with two sections, with each one having two cells with an image, title and subtitle.

So far, I've managed to get the tableview populated with the data, I just for the life of me can't figure out how to set up the sections.

I'm trying to get the first two (sudoku/crossword) in a section called Puzzles and the bottom two (run/fly) in a Section called Arcade.

I have tried multiple turorials online and SO threads and I've hit a dead end.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thank you.

Here's the implementation:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit
import FSUtils



class GamesVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var stackAds: UIStackView!

struct Game {
    var name: String
    var desc: String

}

let games = [
    Game(name: "Sudoku", desc: "The classic game of 9"),
    Game(name: "Crossword", desc: "One more classic time killer"),
    Game(name: "Run", desc: "Run to make your flight!"),
    Game(name: "Fly", desc: "Keep flapping to stay in the air"),
]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        navigationItem.title = "Games"

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if !Settings.shared.adsEnabled {
                self.removeTableViewHeader()
            } else {
                self.tableView.layoutTableHeaderView()
            }
        }
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: animated)
    }

    //tableView
    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int
    {
            return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
            return games.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! TableViewCell// Sets the text of the Label in the Table View Cell
         let game = games[indexPath.row]

         cell.gameTitle?.text = game.name
         cell.gameDesc?.text = game.desc
         cell.gameImg?.image = UIImage(named: game.name)

     return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueSudoku", sender: nil)
            showAd()
            break;
        case 1:
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueCrossword", sender: nil)
            showAd()
        break;
        case 2:
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueRun", sender: nil)
            showAd()
        break;
        case 3:
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueFly", sender: nil)
            showAd()
        break;

            default:
                break;
        }
}

func removeTableViewHeader() {
    stackAds.removeFromSuperview()

}

func showAd() {
    if Settings.shared.adsEnabled {
        AdManager.shared.showAd(fromVC: self)
    }
}

func disableAds() {
    Settings.shared.adsEnabled = false
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.removeTableViewHeader()
    }
}

@IBAction func onRemoveAds(_ sender: Any) {
    #if targetEnvironment(simulator)
        disableAds()
    #else
    for product in InAppPurchases.shared.products {
        if product.productIdentifier == InAppPurchases.RemoveAds {
            FSUtils.presentHud(withTitle: nil, on: view) { finished in
                InAppPurchases.shared.buy(product: product) { result in
                    finished()
                    switch result {
                    case .success:
                        self.disableAds()
                    case .failure(let error):
                        print(error)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    #endif
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start by improving the structure of the data array if you want to create a section

```
struct Game {
    var name: String
    var desc: String
}

let puzzleGames = [
    Game(name: "Sudoku", desc: "The Classic Time Killer"), //Puzzle
    Game(name: "Crossword", desc: "Another Classic"), //Puzzle
]

let arcadeGames = [
    Game(name: "Run", desc: "Keep running"), //Arcade
    Game(name: "Fly", desc: "Keep flying'"), //Arcade
]

let gameSections: [[Games]] = []
```

you can set gameSection on viewDidLoad before call table delegate

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    gameSections = [puzzleGames, arcadeGames]
    // or if u set delegate from storyboard you can reload table after set gameSections
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Then

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int
    {
        return gameSections.count
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return gameSections[section].count
    }
```

from the code above tableview you will have two sections (puzzle and arcade)
the rest you can create a table header to give a title in each section

I hope this matches your expectations, hopefully it helps

Comment: Thanks Faidelse, I try your solution but I get this:
Cannot use instance member 'arcadeGames' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available

Comment: Added in the original post as requested. Thank you so much.

Comment: the error was for let gameSections = [puzzleGames, arcadeGames]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214386/discussion-between-user2358893-and-fadielse).

Comment: Sorted! Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

You need an extra struct representing the sections

```
struct Section {
    let title : String
    let games : [Game]
}

struct Game {
    var name: String
    var desc: String
}

let sections = [Section(title: "Puzzle", games: [Game(name: "Sudoku", desc: "The Classic Time Killer"),
                                                 Game(name: "Crossword", desc: "Another Classic")]),
               Section(title: "Arcade", games: [Game(name: "Run", desc: "Keep running"),
                                                Game(name: "Fly", desc: "Keep flying'")])
]
```

---

Change the data source methods to

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return sections.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return sections[section].games.count
}   

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! TableViewCell// Sets the text of the Label in the Table View Cell
    let game = sections[indexPath.section].games[indexPath.row]
    cell.gameTitle?.text = game.name
    cell.gameDesc?.text = game.desc
    cell.gameImg?.image = UIImage(named: game.name)
    return cell
}
```

And change `didSelectRow` accordingly